# how to run web application in another machine?

Tags: asp.net

I want to run my web application in another machine.My problem is that i have already created virtual directory in iis 7.5 and add web application in it. Its running in my machine properly but i am trying it run in another machine through url and add the ip address along port number but its not found the web page.Plz help me .

Comment: my web application is running in another machine if i close firewall of my system .

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to the machine on which you want to run your web application, then set up a virtual directory on *that* machine. Make sure port 80 (or whatever port you decided to run your web application on) is open on the firewall (probably Windows firewall) too. Then you can access your web app on the other machine with a url like http://hostname, where hostname is the NetBIOS name or IP address of the machine you want to access.

If you get a timeout, then IIS isn't running or the firewall is closed. If you get a 404 error, then your virtual directory isn't set up correctly or you typed an invalid URL.

Comment: you might want to check the bindings and make sure IIS is not only serving to localhost

Comment: if i want to run this web application in LAN so its not possible i setup the vortual directory in each system